# Error converting varchar to numeric in SQL subtract query

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
select SUM(quantity) from Sales join Document on Sales.IdDocument = Document.IdDocument where (IdTipoDocumento = 'vco' or IdTipoDocumento = 'vcr') and IdArticulo = '01-00321' and IdListaEmpresa = 1000129
-
(select SUM(quantity) from Sales join Document on Sales.IdDocument = Document.IdDocument where IdTipoDocumento = 'dco'  and IdArticulo = '01-00321' and IdListaEmpresa = 1000129)
```

If I run each line separately, each query works fine (the first gives 419 as a result, the second 380) but if I try to run the whole thing to get the result (419-380) it tells me "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

They're both supposed to already be numeric (the quantity field is of integer type anyways) so I don't know why the error comes out...

Comment: What is the error number you get ?

Comment: @MuhammedAli Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1

Comment: What's the datatype of `IdListaEmpresa`?

Comment: IdListaEmpresa is numeric

Comment: `419-380`  is not `numeric` and it can not be converted into numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT
(select SUM(quantity) from Sales join Document on Sales.IdDocument = Document.IdDocument 
where (IdTipoDocumento = 'vco' or IdTipoDocumento = 'vcr') and IdArticulo = '01-00321' and 
IdListaEmpresa = 1000129)

-
(select SUM(quantity) from Sales join Document on Sales.IdDocument = Document.IdDocument 
where IdTipoDocumento = 'dco'  and IdArticulo = '01-00321' and IdListaEmpresa = 1000129)
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT SUM(SQ)
FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN (IdTipoDocumento = 'vco' or IdTipoDocumento = 'vcr') THEN SUM(Quantity)
WHEN IdTipoDocumento = 'dco' THEN -1*SUM(Quantity)
END AS SQ
FROM  Sales join Document on Sales.IdDocument = Document.IdDocument 
where (IdTipoDocumento IN ('vco', 'vcr','dco')) and IdArticulo = '01-00321' and 
IdListaEmpresa = '1000129'
GROUP BY IdTipoDocumento) AS T1
```

**Method 3:**

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN IdTipoDocumento IN ('vco', 'vcr') THEN Quantity ELSE -1*Quantity END)
AS SQ
FROM  Sales join Document on Sales.IdDocument = Document.IdDocument 
where (IdTipoDocumento IN ('vco', 'vcr','dco')) and IdArticulo = '01-00321' and 
IdListaEmpresa = 1000129
```

**Method 3a:**

```
   SELECT IdListaEmpresa, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN IdTipoDocumento IN ('vco', 'vcr') 
                  THEN Quantity 
                  ELSE -1*Quantity END) AS SQ
   FROM  Sales join Document on Sales.IdDocument = Document.IdDocument 
   WHERE (IdTipoDocumento IN ('vco', 'vcr','dco')) 
       AND IdArticulo = '01-00321' 
       AND IdListaEmpresa IN (1000129, 1000130, 1,2,3,4,5)
   GROUP BY IdListaEmpresa
```

Comment: Same error. I think it might be saving the results of each sum(quantity) as varchars instead of numbers?

Comment: Can you update your sql statements to add single quotes to IdListaEmpresa like `IdListaEmpresa = '1000129'`

Comment: I tried it. Made no difference, the error remains, IdListaEmpresa is numeric anyways...

Comment: I added a method 2. Can you please try that?

Comment: Method 2 works. It's much more complex than Method 1 but if I can't get the latter to work, I'll take this. Thanks!

Comment: I still need to figure out a way to make Method 1 work, cause there are 7 different IdListaEmpresa I need to run this for and I was hoping to combine all of them into one query (get the result of the sum and subtractions for each IdListaEmpresa in one query).

I need to run this query thousands of times (once for each article) and if I need to run it also once per IdListaEmpresa it's gonna take a huge toll on performance...

Comment: Added Method 3a which groups the data by IdListaEmpressa. Plugin the correct values of IdListaEmpressa in the query and you should be good to go. You can do the same with method 2 also.